Garbage values when reading from a sim7600 module using jetson nano
I've got a python3 script to run on a jetson nano board and to that board, there's a sim7600 module connected. All the connections are being made correctly, and the voltages are what's expected. The problem here is that when sending any at command to the sim7600, i get some weird characters as the response. I'll leave a simple script im using to test the module.
Note: When using the termite software, I'm able to communicate with the module at the desired baudrate.
Here's a small script to debug the problem
import serial
import time

class sim7600:
def __init__(self):
    self.ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyTHS1", baudrate = 9600, 
    timeout = 1, bytesize =  serial.EIGHTBITS, 
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

    time.sleep(2)

def readData(self):
    line = ""
    lines = []
    while self.ser.in_waiting:
        line = self.ser.readline().decode(errors='ignore').strip()
        if line:
            print(line)
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            break
    return lines

def sendData(self,command, timeout):
    try:
        fullcommand = "{}\r\n".format(command)
        self.ser.write_timeout = timeout
        bytes_written = self.ser.write(fullcommand.encode())
        if bytes_written == len(fullcommand):
            print("Sent: {}".format(fullcommand))
        else:
            print("Not all the data was written")
    except serial.serialutil.SerialTimeoutException:
        print("A timeout was reached")

my_module = sim7600()
while True:

response = my_module.sendData("at")
print(response)

received_message = my_module.readData()


so, you are doing self.ser.readline().decode(errors='ignore'), which means you assume that the bytes you are reading represent UTF-8 encoded text. Is that what you actually expect? What output are you getting, what output would you expect?

@juanpa.arrivillaga thank you for your comment.
Im getting weird characters, can't actually read them. The output I'm expecting is indeed utf-8 encoded text, since it's the same logic I'm using on the sim800l module. I should receive "OK" but instead receive a bunch of weird symbols. If I remove the "errors=ignore" parameter I get a decode exception, that's the only reason I'm using it, to try to get any clue of what's happening.
Thank you

Why don't you actually provide the outputs? In any case, if you are getting a decoding error, the bytes are not UTF-8 encoded.
